# Get int from textView

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the int value from a textView, the value inside will always be a number just in string, I set it like this

```
int randomNumber = rng.nextInt(6) + 1;
    switch (randomNumber) {
        case 1:
            imageViewDice.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice1);
            textView.setText("Tiraste un 1!");

            if (player1.getText().equals("")) {
                player1.setText("1");
            } else {
                player2.setText("1");
            }
            break;
//rest of cases 2, 3, 4, 5, & 6
```

I need the int value of this to be able to compare then to see which player (1 or 2) has the highest number, something like this

```
//this doesnt work 
int value1 = Integer.parseInt(player1.getText().toString());
int value2 = Integer.parseInt(player2.getText().toString());

if (value1 > value2) {
    result.setText("Jugador 1");
} else if (value1 < value2) {
    result.setText("Jugador 2");
} else {
    result.setText("Empate!");
}
```

What is the correct way to get the value so that the comparison can be made?

Comment: i think your code is most case the two player TextView have same value because you set initial value for player one same to player two in your switch statement 

and in your code compare between values will print empty

Comment: `if (player1.getText() == "")` -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: @MahmoudAbuElheja what it's doing it checking if player one has already been filled if not then it fills player one and then it fills player two, what I'm trying to do is take `"1"` and turn it in a int  `1`, so that the comparion between those values will work since they need to be an int to check if one is greater than the other one

Comment: @a_local_nobody yes I did change that in my code a little while ago, I'll edit the code in the question

Comment: @Nancy can add your full code to show the logic between textView

Comment: @a_local_nobody I'm displaying what each player got in a textView according to the randomNumber, how would I use the randomNumber like you're suggesting?

Comment: Before parsing string value to integer, please check / debug if your string value can be a valid integer. Non-empty, or with non-numeric alpha character etc.

Answer (score 1):

if you set static, you can very easily read in various classes:

```
player1.setText(Fraction.getP1()+"");
player2.setText(Fraction.getP2()+"");

if(Fraction.getP1()>Fraction.getP2())
   result.setText("Jugador 1");
```

new class

```
public class Fraction {

    private static int p1=0;
    private static int p2=0;

    public static int getP1(){
        return p1;
    }
    public static int getP2(){
        return p2;
    }
    public static void setP1(int p1fraction){
        Fraction.p1 = p1fraction; //Fraction is your class name
    }
    public static void setP2(int p2fraction){
        p2 = p2fraction;
    }

}
```